Kube-state-metrics data collected by prometheus outside the cluster was discarded
Due to some historical reasons, my prometheus is deployed outside the k8s cluster. I have multiple k8s clusters, and each cluster deploys kube-state-metrics. I use static_configs to collect metric data from different clusters. The configuration is as follows。
scrape_configs:
- job_name: global-kube-state-metrics
  honor_labels: true
  honor_timestamps: true
  scrape_interval: 30s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: http
  follow_redirects: true
  enable_http2: true
  static_configs:
    - targets:
      - 10.29.14.212:30897
      labels:
        cluster: global

another one，
scrape_configs:
- job_name: k8s-18-86-kube-state-metrics
  honor_labels: true
  honor_timestamps: true
  scrape_interval: 30s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: http
  follow_redirects: true
  enable_http2: true
  static_configs:
    - targets:
      - 10.29.18.87:31770
      labels:
        cluster: k8s-18-86

I add a label cluster to each cluster to distinguish,
But my prometheus will discard some data,like this，
ts=2024-10-11T03:14:31.016Z caller=scrape.go:1738 level=warn component="scrape manager" scrape_pool=global-kube-state-metrics target=http://10.29.14.212:30897/metrics msg="Error on ingesting samples with different value but same timestamp" num_dropped=1
ts=2024-10-11T03:15:01.015Z caller=scrape.go:1738 level=warn component="scrape manager" scrape_pool=global-kube-state-metrics target=http://10.29.14.212:30897/metrics msg="Error on ingesting samples with different value but same timestamp" num_dropped=1

Can someone help me check the problem or guide me on how to adjust the configuration
